# How can I roleplay The Comedian from Watchmen?

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun

My DM is preparing Shadowrun campaign for our group and I decided to play an evil character. Since I'm fan of Watchmen, I decided to borrow character The Comedian. The problem is that I never played evil character (I generally didn't play a lot of characters since I'm fairly new to RPGs) and I don't want to ruin whole campaign for everyone by being total dick. Those who know this character know what he did in his past.

I would like to hear some suggestions about what could be his motivations and goals. Also I wanna be helpful to my group but at the same time I want to keep some distance from them, if you know what I mean (as far as I know The Comedian never really had real friends).

Btw I'm not saying that The Comedian is necessarily a bad guy. I just want to play him that way.

Comment: Yeah I know, I suggested it to my DM but he said that I would want to kill my group since they will most likely all be criminals.

Comment: The now out of print DC Heroes system had a supplement for Watchmen. While the rules don't apply it might help you with how to play the Comedian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd start out by not thinking of the character as evil, instead I'd play him as *sociopath*. You might not go out of your way to concoct nefarious evil schemes, but as a general mode of behavior you are not constrained by normal morals in getting what you want. If someone has what you want then it would only be the consequences to you personally than constrain your actions. Theft, betrayal, blackmail or murder are not social taboos for you.  You might not murder the doughnut man today because -- whose going to make you doughnuts tomorrow?

Always, always get dirty on people and bend them to your will. Why not take a lover but remember to get embarrassing photos of them for later use? Take your friend gambling and lend him some money: best not tell his wife, unless you need to. Find peoples' weakness and feed it until you can use it to get what you want.

Why not?  Social norms should not apply to you!  You are superior to the herd; they are there to help you fulfil you ambitions and nothing more.  If your public image takes a battering, hire a publicist and start a charitable foundation.

Lance Armstrong provides an excellent real life case study; for a fictional character, try Frank Underwood from *House of Cards*.

Comment: Love the answer(+1).  I made a few edits for spelling and punctuation and flow.  If the meaning is missed, please revert and maybe just correct the minor errors.

Comment: Yeah, me too. This is exactly what I needed to hear.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thanks, little rushed with little sleep, glad the meaning came across.

Comment: *Might* want to write the bit about Lance Armstrong a bit differently. Right now this appears to say that he's a sociopath, when (I think?) what you might have been trying to say is that he's ambitious and climbed over people to get his success.

Comment: I've no problem with the [description](http://www.mrmediatraining.com/2013/01/20/is-lance-armstrong-a-sociopath/#sthash.Z3HhKcEm.dpuf), "a pathological liar who lacks remorse, is manipulative and superficially charming, and who fails to take responsibility for his actions". Perfect case study for building a Comedian character.

Comment: Looks like I was prescient on Frank Underwood...